# create android battery widget animated when charging

Tags: android, android-widget, animated

I want to create battery animated widget when battery is charging.I want to show some images continuously.
I use an `ImageView` like below:

```
 <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/batterycharging_anim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@anim/batterycharging" />
```

and batterycharging anim file is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list
    android:oneshot="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/battery_c_10" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/battery_c_20" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/battery_c_30" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/battery_c_40" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/battery_c_50" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/battery_c_60" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/battery_c_70" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/battery_c_80" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/battery_c_90" android:duration="25" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/battery_c_100" android:duration="25" />
</animation-list>
```

and here is my method for updating widget:

```
private RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context)
    {
        RemoteViews widgetView  = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.batterywidget_layout);

        if(status== BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING)
        {


        }
    }
```

what should i do next? what should i put in if block??

Answer (score 0):

I think a basic implementation would be this

Updated:

Found out you can't use Animation in RemoteViews. but you can use a Progressbar in your layout and set android:indeterminateDrawable to your Animation and make it visible and invisible according to battery status

Comment: can't use findViewbyId() method because it is not define in WidgetService class.

Comment: Oh Sorry. I thought it was in an Activity.

can you use widgetView.startAnimation?